# NestJS enableVersioning not defined?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to follow the [simple guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning) on adding versioning to my API in NestJS. But the `app` instance does not seem to have the `enableVersioning()`. There also doesn't seem to be any `VersionType` enum exported by any Nest package.

I'd love to be able to add versioning.

[image]

Comment: you might have forgot to upgrade `@nestjs/core` to v8. Or reload VSC. btw `VersioningType` should be imported from `@nestjs/common`

Comment: @MicaelLevi great catch. Will try that. I‘m still on v7. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`enableVersioning` was added in `@nestjs/common@8` and `@nestjs/core@8`. The docs are current for Nest v8, for v7 [you can view the docs here](https://docs.nestjs.com/v7/). Make sure you're using the latest version to have access to *all* of the features in the docs.